# How to open a form and close it programmatically after a while

Tags: c#, winforms

I Have a button on a form, and I want to open another form on this form using button click,  but after 1 min that new opened form must be closed automatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: thanks  now i have tow form for example  form1 and form2  in form1  there are button  i want when click this button showing form2 on form1 but   i need Open for period 1min after this time close ..

Comment: FormPopoup frm = new FormPopoup();
            frm.Show();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            frm.Close();   im using this but the problem this form showing in task bar  in need on this form i maked ShowDailog but when showing not going Thread..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of these options:

- You can use `Task.Delay()` and close the form in `.ContinueWith()` if the form is still open.
- Or you can use a `Timer` in your second form and set the interval 60000 ms, then in `Tick` event call `this.Close();`

**Task Example:**

In the below example, after 5 seconds I check if the form is still open, I close it:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var f = new Form();

    Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith((t) =>
    {
        if (f == null || f.Disposing || f.IsDisposed)
            return;

        f.Invoke(new Action(() => { f.Close(); }));
    });

    f.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying   error

Comment: system.threading.tasks.task" does not contain a definition for Delay

Comment: FormPopoup frm = new FormPopoup();
            frm.Show();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            frm.Close();   im using this but the problem this form showing in task bar  in need on this form i maked ShowDailog but when showing not going Thread..

Comment: @mahmoud **(1)** Don't forget to add  `using System.Threading.Tasks;`
**(2)** Don't use `Thread.Sleep()` because it blocks the UI thread and your form seem to be locked or disabled. **(3)** To not show a form in taskbar, set `f.ShowInTaskBar=false;` **(4)** The above trick also works for `ShowDialog` **(5)** You also can use `Timer` trick as I described above.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback @mahmoud When you accept an answer, you can also kindly click on up arrow to vote for it, It is not compulsory at all but reasonable and it's your kindness :)